# Bag data structure in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

**Definition**:

> [Bag or Multiset](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/bag.html) is a set data structure which allows duplicate elements, provided the order of retrieval is not significant.

Now as I read python documentation it is told that a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) behaves as a Bag data structure. But I am confused if we can use List or Tuple as an alternative?

One possible flaw as I can see is that `removing` an element is not allowed in Bag. Also, normally retrieving an element in List or Tuple takes O(n) time but Bag can be implemented via hashing to allow constant time removal.

**Question**:

Can we use List or Tuple as a Bag data structure?

Comment: Do you have one, explicit question you want to know the answer to?

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta done!

Comment: @vivek  - why not use a set itself? The elements are not ordered in a set. If you're looking for immutability you can use a tuple.

Comment: @praroh1 remember `Set` doesn't allow duplicate elements.

Comment: @vivek - yes! Btw, what operations do you want? Do you want to be able to add elements into the bag later on or are all the elements known at the time of creating it and a `ele in bag` test sufficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can we use List or Tuple as a Bag data structure?

Yes.

It would require some code to get the structure correct, and you'd likely want a list as they are mutable. But you can add duplicates to a list, count them and remove them.

Comment: `It would require some code to get the structure correct` you mean writing a wrapper class / function to fit the Bag API?

Comment: Hmm, so if I the piece of code is not a public facing API then I can use list without any fear.

Answer (score 1):

No.

- The elements of a bag are unordered and non-unique.
- The elements of a Counter are unordered and non-unique.
- The elements of a set are unordered and unique.
- The elements of a list (and tuple) are ordered and non-unique.

A Counter behaves like a bag of m&m's.  A list behaves like a pez dispenser - the order of its elements is significant.

```
> a = {1, 2, 3}
> b = {1, 2, 3}
> c = {1, 3, 2}
> a == b
True
> a == c
True

> a = Counter((1, 2, 3))
> b = Counter((1, 2, 3))
> c = Counter((1, 3, 2))
> a == b
True
> a == c
True

> a = [1, 2, 3]
> b = [1, 2, 3]
> c = [1, 3, 2]
> a == b
True
> a == c
False
```